# Are there any other DC characters mentioned in the Watchmen universe (prior to the Doomsday Clock crossover)?

Tags: dc, watchmen, watchmen-2009

In the movie *Watchmen (2009)*, we can see posters of Batman during the credit sequence in beginning and 'Superman' was also mentioned during the flashback scene of Dr. Manhattan which suggests that the DC characters do exist in the *film* Watchmen universe as fictional comicbook characters.

Are there any DC characters ever mentioned in the *comic-book* version (prior to the [Doomsday Clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_Clock_(comics)) crossover comics)?

Comment: Aren't they set in the same universe/multiverse thing? Wouldn't the answer be "all of them"?

Comment: well they do and don't :p Doctor Manhattan's actions create the universe for the DC characters. so in a way, yes.

Comment: @Edlothiad  - OP dealt with that in the question. They're only explicitly shown to be the same fictional universe after a DC crossover event called The Doomsday Clock

Answer (score 5):

[Doc Savage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doc_Savage) and [The Shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shadow) are mentioned in the fictional "*Under the Hood*" segment at the end of [*Watchmen #1*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Watchmen_Vol_1_1)

> The world of **Doc
> Savage and The Shadow** was one
> of absolute values, where what
> was good was never in the slight-
> est doubt and where what was
> evil inevitably suffered some fit-
> ting punishment.

Action Comics #1 also gets a mention. Note that Superman, Zatara, Doc Savage and the Shadow are all explicitly called out as examples of *fictional* superheroes whose star waned once there were stories about real superheroes like Ozymandias and Captain Metropolis.

> For me, it all started in 1938, the year when they invented the super-hero. I was too old
> for comic books when the first issue of ACTION COMICS came out, or at least too old to read
> them in public without souring my promotion chances, but I noticed a lot of the little kids on
> my beat reading it and couldn’t resist asking one of them if I could glance through it. I figured if anybody saw me I could put it all down to keeping a good relationship with the youth of the community.
>
> ...
>
> I’d never been entirely sure what
> Lamont Cranston was up to with Margo Lane, but I’d bet it was nowhere near as innocent and
> wholesome as Clark Kent’s relationship with her namesake Lois. Of course, all of these old
> Characters are gone and forgotten now, but I’m willing to bet that there are at least a few older readers out there who will remember enough to know what I’m talking about.

---

[Superman](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_(Clark_Kent)) and [The Flash](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Flash) (erroneously referred to as Flash-Man) get a mention in [*Watchmen #3*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Watchmen_Vol_1_3)

[image]

---

[Mr Spock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(DC_Comics)) gets a mention in Watchmen #9.

[image]